# How to display EditorGUILayout.PropertyField's content to a textbox?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to display input from an EditorGUILayout.PropertyField into a text box?

[image]

Here's what I came up with:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class clue : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text hintText;  

void Start()
{
    HintText.Text = EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(levelInfo.FindPropertyRelative("clue"));
}
}
```

I tried. Thanks to whoever could help.

Comment: What is `levelInfo`? I think you also missed that `EditorGUILayout.PropertyField` is ment to be used in a CustomEditor script and makes absolutely no sense where you used it. Additionally your code wont be build-able since it uses the `UnityEditor` namespace which is not available outside of Unity itlsef.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add a public string field to the class?

It will be displayed in the Inspector, where you can make an input and then assign this string value to the `hintText.text`.

If you are using custom Inspector drawers to make some custom, complex structures, consider creating a separate non-MonoBehaviour class with desired structure and use `System.Serializable` attribute to make the objects of the class to be visible in the Inspector. Just like this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html

Comment: I'm planning on using it multiple times. The idea is that there are multiple words in the game and each of them has a unique "clue" inside a pop up text box.

Comment: Here's a pic of the UI: https://imgur.com/a/opXmkPx where all of the words in "Clue" will appear in the same text box depending which word is active.

Comment: Well then I'd suggest to create a ScriptableObject

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html

there you can specify a list or dictionary of your data and have a static property to access those values.